# exim4 multi domain relay - update-exim4.conf.conf

Tags: debian, exim, conf

I am trying to configure a Debian vServer to relay mails for multiple domains pointed to the vServer. The vServer has a fixed ip. The webserver for all domains is working fine.

With one domain the relaying is working as expected but I can not add another domain to uptedate-exim4.conf.conf. It keeps saying:

/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf: 20: domain2.com: not found
/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf: 23: domain2.com: not found

What is it trying to tell me? Where is it looking for domain2.com? Why does it always work for domain1.com?

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='domain1.com';'domain2.com'
dc_local_interfaces='0.0.0.0'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='domain1.com';'domain2.com'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='true'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Note: The configuration is probably not doing what I want it to but I can not test it because of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized the problem, the whole list has to be quoted, not every single domain. Like so:

```
'domain1.com;domain2.com'
```